# MVC 3 Razor pass webgrid row data to controller using actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid, actionlink

I have a webgrid with an actionlink which I want to use to edit the selected row in a new view. I know that I can use an actionlink to supply an arguement to my actionresult method but I don't know how to pass the webgrid's row data to my controller apart from using actionlink.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>
    Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New User", "CreateUser")
</p>
<div class="webgrid-wrapper">
    @model IEnumerable<UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model_Add_Users>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Jobs";
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, canSort: true, rowsPerPage: 15, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", fieldNamePrefix: "gridItem");

}
    @grid.GetHtml(
    fillEmptyRows: true,
        tableStyle: "webgrid",
                alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
                headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
                footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
                selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
            rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
columns: new[] {
    //grid.Column("ApplicationId"),
    //grid.Column("salutation"),

    //grid.Column("PasswordSalt"),

     grid.Column("FirstName"),

    //grid.Column("LoweredEmail"),
    //grid.Column("PasswordQuestion"),
    //grid.Column("PasswordAnswer"),

    // grid.Column("PasswordFormat"),
    grid.Column("LastName"),
    grid.Column("Password"),
    grid.Column("isactive"),
    //grid.Column("IsLockedOut"),
    grid.Column("email"),
   grid.Column("module_name"), 

    //grid.Column("LastLoginDate"),
    //grid.Column("LastPasswordChangedDate"),
    //grid.Column("LastLockoutDate"),

    //grid.Column("FailedPasswordAttemptCount"),
    //grid.Column("FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart"),
    //grid.Column("FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount"),
    //grid.Column("FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart"),
   // Rest of grid columns, seen previously
    @*grid.Column(
       "",
        header: "Actions",
        format: @<text>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.email }) 
    </text>
    )   , 
     grid.Column(
       "",
        header: "Actions",
        format: @<text>
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.email })
    </text>
    )    *@
@*     grid.Column(
            header:"", 
            format:@<text><div id="btnSelectedRow">
                "@item.GetSelectLink("Edit")</div></text>
            ),*@


     grid.Column(
            header:"", 
            format:@<text><div id="btnSelectedRow">
                "@Html.ActionLink("Edit record", 
                        "EditUser",
                        "UserManager",
                                       new {selectedRow = grid.SelectedRow },
                        null
                        )</div></text>
            )
})
    @if (grid.HasSelection)
    {
        var record = grid.SelectedRow;
@*@RenderPage("~/Views/UserManager/EditUser.cshtml", new { record = grid.SelectedRow })*@

    }
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function jQueryUIStyling() {
            $('input:button, input:submit').button();

            // Style tables.
            $('.webgrid-wrapper').addClass('ui-grid ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all');
            $('.webgrid-title').addClass('ui-grid-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-top');
            jQueryTableStyling();
        }

        //
        // Style tables using jQuery UI theme. This function is 
        // split out separately so that it can be part of the AJAX
        // callback of the WebGrid WebHelper in ASP.NET MVC.
        //
        function jQueryTableStyling() {
            $('.webgrid').addClass('ui-grid-content ui-widget-content');
            $('.webgrid-header').addClass('ui-state-default');
            $('.webgrid-footer').addClass('ui-grid-footer ui-widget-header ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-clearfix');
        }
    });

</script>
```

**My controller**

```
 public ActionResult EditUser(System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid record)
        {
            record.ToString();

            return View();
        }
```

**Summary**

How to pass row data using ActionLink from one view to another via ActionResult method.

Comment: Doesn't anyone know the solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options, really: have your action take the user Id and look the user up, or have each row of your grid contain a form which sends all the user details to the action when you click 'edit'. Which of those you choose depends on what your action is supposed to do:

1. If it redirects to a form where the user can edit the user they selected, use the first approach
2. If it takes all the user details and saves an updated user, use the second approach

**Edit**

To pass the id you can use this for the action link:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Edit record",
    "EditUser",
    "UserManager",
    new { id = item.email })
```

...and this for the action signature:

```
public ActionResult EditUser(string id)
```

Comment: I want to take the Id. Do you have any examples of this. I am trying to pass the row values to my ActionResult, with an Id I could easily query the database and retrieve the correct data. The problem is I don't know what parameter I am meant to supply to the ActionLink.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do it like that. How does item.email have the correct value?

Comment: I'm not sure what `item` is, to be honest - I just copied it off the code for the delete link in your question...

Comment: How It will be accessible to each row.?